# SharePoint ItemDisplayTemplate thumbnail and qtip2

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, jsom, sharepoint-search

I would like to get the thumbnail from an url and use it with [qtip2](http://qtip2.com/).

And I can see that some item display templates are able to generate those thumbnails from the url, but I don't need to use the search content web part.

I have used the same display template: **Item_WebPage_HoverPanel.html** that generates it's .js correspondent script, but I have got some bugs.
I made some modifications like described in [here](http://www.techmikael.com/2013/04/how-to-enable-page-previews-in.html), but it was not enought.
I am getting some bugs saying that Srch element is not defined.
I have tested in a page that is using this display item template, I have changed the url and it is displaying fine the links, even links from the internet.

I have tried to use the url directly on the qtip2 and it is opening an iframe with the page directly, where you can interact with that. That is not what I would like to have.

[PagePeeker](https://pagepeeker.com/) is a service that is able to do it, but it is an external service and it just works on internet, it doesn't search in the intranet.

**To be clear, the question is:** How can I take advantage of the item display template from SharePoint to show thumbnails for intranet and internet ? I don't need to crawl anything.

**EDIT**: I was able to load all required scripts for displaying template run without errors by exporting the search result webpart and importing in my page.
No I would like to hide the div where this webpart is made and apply the hover panel in a container div related with the http link I would add to this div.
I have also discovered that the preview screenshot is SharePoint is an iframe where you can't interact.

That is used for creating an iframe and is embedded in the page.

Comment: I am not clear on what question you are asking.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott I edited the question at the end to make it more clear. I don't need any crawling or webpart related with the search, but only it's javaScript that allows me to use thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the search content result that uses the default item display template (`item_site_hoverpanel.js`) for hovering has the method bellow:

It first gets an iframe by using the method:

```
Srch.SiteSearchUtil.populateSiteSearchResults(ctx.CurrentItem.csr_Path, siteResultsId, query, id + HP.ids.noData, timeZoneId);
```

Later it loads the already downloaded iframe, if you hover again.

```
if(loadSiteFrame){
                AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function(){ULSqag:;
                    HP.loadSiteViewer(ctx.CurrentItem.id, ctx.CurrentItem.id + HP.ids.inner, id + HP.ids.viewer, ctx.CurrentItem.csr_Path, "glass_" + id + HP.ids.viewer);
                });
            }
```

The method `loadSiteViewer` method is defined at the `SearchUI.debugger.js` file as:

```
        this.loadSiteViewer = function(resultId, hpId, iframeId, viewerUrl, glassViewerId){
            var result = $get(resultId);
            var iframe = $get(iframeId);  
            var glassViewer = $get(glassViewerId);          
            var hp = $get(hpId);
            if(result && iframe && hp && glassViewer){
...
```

I don't know if there is any SharePoint security checking on those iframes, but some websites are possible to be loaded from intranet, others not (`www.google.com`), for example, since they have some iframe protection.

Since Google is sending an "`X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`" response header.